# How can i play a death animation on Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I want to play a death animation to my enemy. Basically, he has an idle animation and I would like to play the death animation when he dies, and after one or two seconds, the GameObject gets deleted. I'm new to coding, so a basic solution would be better :) .
Here's my coding:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyHealthManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int enemyHealth;
    public GameObject deathEffect;
    public int pointsOnDeath;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (enemyHealth <= 0) 
        {
            Instantiate (deathEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            ScoreManager.AddPoints (pointsOnDeath);
            Destroy (gameObject);

        }
    }




    public void giveDamage(int damageToGive)
    {
        enemyHealth -= damageToGive;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Unity! Using an `AnimatorController` in your project and corresponding `Animator` components on your `GameObject` that you want to die is going to be your friend here as well.

You can check out a great tutorial by Unity about Animator Controllers [here](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/animator-controllers-2019-3#), but basically, it's a state machine. Based on what state your object is in, you can control which game object animations are active and you can set triggers in your game logic to trigger a transition to another state.

This is great for cases like triggering death animations.

In your case, you'd want one state for `idle`, and one state for `death`. You'd have a connection between your `death` and `idle` state.

You'd set a trigger named `die`. You'd make it so that the state `idle` only moves to state `death` when your `die` trigger is triggered in the game logic.

So, step 1:
You'd create a new `AnimatorController` Scriptable Object from the Editor, and then edit it in the `Animator` window. Make your desired state machine with the desired animations and that `ScriptableObject` will be saved in a project folder.

Step 2: Add an `Animator` component on your `GameObject` that you want to affect. It has an `AnimatorController` component - add your newly created controller here.

Step 3: In your game logic script, you'd have a reference to that `Animator` component:

```
...
public int enemyHealth;
public GameObject deathEffect;
public int pointsOnDeath;
public Animator animComponent;
...
```

Then when you hit your condition, you'd do something like this:

```
if (enemyHealth < 0){
    animComponent.SetTrigger("die");
}
```

Then your `AnimatorController` will move from your previous state to `death`, and your animation that you set will play.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: [`AnimatorController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorController.html) is no component .. it is a `ScriptableObject` .. also it doesn't have `SetTrigger` .. do you mean the [`Animator`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html) component? Note further that `AnimatorController` only exists in the `UnityEditor` namespace and will throw errors when trying to build the app ;)

Comment: @derHugo Great catch, looks like I got mixed up! It's been awhile since I've worked with these components in Unity. I edited my answer to reflect that you need to both set up the `AnimatorController` `ScriptableObject` in the project and then attach the `Animator` component  to the object later.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a function called PlayAnimationAndDestroy() as a void and inside it put the Destroy (this.gameObject, 2f) and then animator.Play("deathAnim");

In the Destroy the number after the comma is the time Unity will wait to destroy the object so you need to check the duration of your animation in the timeline and put that duration in the Destroy ().

Another way to do this is to press the record button inside the animation at the end of it and change a public variable. In the script you will put a simple if() and If that variable has changed you destroy the object.

The third way is to use animation events (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html) but for your usage the first two options are easier :)

Comment: Or just put the death animation in the animation controller and set the trigger. Leave no way back and at the end of the anim have it trigger the destroy with an animation event

Comment: no no, why does the AnimationController need to know about your object being destroyed?